# Options binding with Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Sure this must be something stupid I'm doing but I'm having a real issue populating a select element and setting the selected value using Knockout to consistently work.  I have a ASP.NET view which has a number of select options and I need to set the selected values with data from the server.

Sometimes these bind correctly but more often than not the selectedValue is not selected - is it the order I'm doing things in?

When using ko.mapping to setting observable properties I can't get this to work at all so have been setting individual observables values but even this doesn't work all the time.

```
 <select data-bind="options: possibleValues, optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'Id',value: selectedValue,  optionsCaption: 'Select Value...'">                                                                                                   

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedValue = ko.observable();
  self.possibleValues = ko.observableArray();

 function GetValues() {
  $.ajax({
  url:"http:/abc.com/api/GetValues",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "GET",
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.values, function(i,option){
          self.possibleValues.push(option);
      });
  }

}

function GetInitialValue() {
  $.ajax({
  url:"http:/abc.com/api/GetValue",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "GET",
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {

     *using ko.mapping doesn't work at all?*

     self.selectedValue1(data1.Id)
     self.selectedValue2(data2.Id)
     self.selectedValue3(data3.Id)
  }
});
}

}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: where do you actually call GetValues and GetInitialValue to populate that data?

Comment: they are coming from the server via a MVC controller method which returns JSON.

Comment: I can see that, I asked where those functions are actually called

Comment: the functions are called on page load, within <Script> tag